# firebird3.0.service failed because the control process exited with error code. How to start firebird?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, firebird, firebird-3.0

I'm working with firebird3.0 database suddenly my database is stopped working and when i have checked server status by

```
$ /etc/init.d/firebird3.0 status
```

i see server is stopped

> ● firebird3.0.service - Firebird Database Server ( SuperServer )
>      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/firebird3.0.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>      Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-05-16 19:01:13 IST; 29s ago
>     Process: 9628 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/fbguard -pidfile /run/firebird3.0/default.pid -daemon -forever (code=exited, status=252)
>
> May 16 19:00:58 ADMIN-I-61 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi3PE.png): Starting Firebird Database Server ( SuperServer )...
>   May 16 19:01:13 ADMIN-I-61 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi3PE.png): firebird3.0.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=252
>   May 16 19:01:13 ADMIN-I-61 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi3PE.png): Failed to start Firebird Database Server ( SuperServer ).
>   May 16 19:01:13 ADMIN-I-61 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi3PE.png): firebird3.0.service: Unit entered failed state.
>   May 16 19:01:13 ADMIN-I-61 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi3PE.png): firebird3.0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

when i'm trying following commands to start server

```
/etc/init.d/firebird3.0 start
/etc/init.d/firebird3.0 restart
```

it returns me

```
[....] Starting firebird3.0 (via systemctl): firebird3.0.serviceJob for firebird3.0.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status firebird3.0.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

My today's firebird.log file is looks like this

```
ADMIN-I-61  Thu May 16 11:06:37 2019
    /opt/firebird/bin/fbguard: guardian starting /opt/firebird/bin/firebird



ADMIN-I-61  Thu May 16 11:07:26 2019
    INET/inet_error: bind errno = 98


ADMIN-I-61  Thu May 16 11:07:27 2019
    startup:INET_connect:
    Unable to complete network request to host "ADMIN-I-61".
    Error while listening for an incoming connection.
    Address already in use


ADMIN-I-61  Thu May 16 11:07:27 2019
    /opt/firebird/bin/fbguard: /opt/firebird/bin/firebird terminated due to startup error (2)



ADMIN-I-61  Thu May 16 11:07:27 2019
    /opt/firebird/bin/fbguard: /opt/firebird/bin/firebird terminated due to startup error (2)



ADMIN-I-61  Thu May 16 12:22:35 2019
    /opt/firebird/bin/fbguard: guardian starting /opt/firebird/bin/firebird
```

I have check ports

[image: Screenshot of ports details]

please help...!

Comment: on Windows there is a file `c:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_1\firebird.log` and I think a similar file should be in Linux somewhere around `/var/log` - is there some detailed errors in it ? Also, Ubuntu is Debian fork and there is one article about exit code 252 at https://bugs.debian.org/859234

Comment: Hi @Arioch'The, thanks for suggestion. Please check my updated question, i have added log file content.

Comment: `Address already in use` do u maybe have other interbase or firebird services (different version, different install path) running there that are had already taken the TCP port? can u use `netstat` or what is there in Linux to determine who might be holding that socket already? can you specify non-standard TCP ports using `firebird.conf` ?

Comment: The error suggest that something is already bound to the port (default is 3050). As Aroich 'The suggests, check if you have another version of Firebird running or something else that has claimed port 3050.

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel, i have added port details of my system.

Comment: this "::::" probably means IPv6 protocol, there also should be IPv4 protocol ports too. I don't know if Firebird/Linux has IPv6 support, but even then the primary protocol is IPv4. Anyway, check the `firebird.conf` file of your new FB3 service to see which two ports your new Firebird wants to use, and maybe to change them to non-default values.

Comment: additionally, your `netstat` asks to be run as root as the very first line!  Please try using `sudo` or `su` to run it. This, frankly, seems more and more going from SQL *PROGRAMMING* (topic of Stack Overflow) into Linux Server ADMINISTRATION (topic of Server Fault and Super User sites).

Comment: As the netstat output shows, you already have something bound on port 3050 (possibly another instance of Firebird, but we don't know as this information is hidden as you didn't run with sudo). I suggest that you take this question to the Firebird-support list. This will probably require more troubleshooting and Stack Overflow is not a suitable venue for troubleshooting as already indicated by the number of comments..

Comment: I have restarted system and check $ /etc/init.d/firebird3.0 status . Its working now automatically.

Comment: Well that would suggest it had already been started, or you did an update and the existing running service was never stopped. Anyway, good to hear it is now solved.

Answer (score 1):

When installing the firebird from the package deb, the line in the file `/etc/firebird/3.0/firebird.conf` was uncommented:

```
RemoteBindAddress = localhost
```

Comment out this line:

```
**#RemoteBindAddress = localhost**
```

Default:

```
RemoteBindAddress =
```

After changes, you must restart the service firebird.